# java insert data into Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I translate the function to the flowing application
The application use PreparedStatement pstmt to insert String array of two dimention,when i make it start ,problems appeared like the photo

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public static void main(String[] args){

java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
        url, user, password);
```

the String array to write into databace.

```
String[][] sheetContent={{"100007"," 钢笔", "200", "xxx"},{"100020", "鞋子","700", "AAA"}};
int rows=2;
int columns = 4;
String sql = "INSERT INTO product(编号,商品名,单价,提供商) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        for(int r=0;r<rows;r++){
            for(int c=0;c<columns;c++){
                pstmt.setString(c, sheetContent[r][c]);
            }
        }
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

[image]

Comment: Indexes to `setString()` is 1-based, not 0-based. Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should start Index of preparedStatement from 1 ,
what you are doing is starting from 0.

index = must starts with index integer 1.

pstmt.setString(index, sheetContent[r][c]);

example: pstmt.setString(1, sheetContent[r][c]);
pstmt.setString(2, sheetContent[r][c]);

Answer (score 1):

You need to be clever with how you use your column indices:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
for (int r=0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c=0; c < columns; c++) {
        int index = 1 + (r * columns) + c;
        pstmt.setString(index, sheetContent[r][c]);
    }
}
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Why would `(r * columns)` be required? It would increase the parameter index based on row index; this doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Despite my comment in regards to correctness, I believe that the OP should suggest an edit to Tim's answer which pointed to the correct direction instead of posting his own answer. I would upvote Tim's corrected answer.

Comment: @Cascader Thanks for defending me buddy.  The idea behind my answer is to translate two dimensions (row, column) into a single dimension index which the prepared statement requires.  This is all there is to it.

Comment: Your idea is clear and certainly in the right direction. However, the statement has a finite number of parameters (i.e. 4) but should the code run against 50 rows, the `index` would grow to a maximum of `1 + (49 *4) + 3` (since `r` would reach 49 and c would reach 3, according to `for` limits). This would result in error while executing / parsing the statement.

Comment: He should ensure that the columns exist first.  This does not make my answer invalid.